# Combine two variables conditionally

Tags: r, date

```
visit_1=as.Date(c("2013-03-22", "2013-05-25", "NA", "2013-02-19", "NA", "2013-04-22",    "2013-06-22", "2013-03-28", "NA", "NA", "2012-12-28" ) )
visit_2=as.Date(c("2013-05-01", "NA", "2013-02-17", "NA", "2013-02-21", "NA", "NA", "NA", "2013-08-22", "2013-03-18", "NA" ) )
mydata=data.frame(visit_1, visit_2, today)
```

How do I create a new variable that combines visit_1 and visit_2? I want something like this; in cases of two visits, take the earlier visit date:

```
visit=as.Date(c("2013-03-22", "2013-05-25", "2013-02-17", "2013-02-19", "2013-02-21", "2013-04-22", "2013-06-22", "2013-03-28", "2013-08-22", "2013-03-18", "2012-12-28" ))
mydata=data.frame(visit_1, visit_2, visit)
```

I feel like there is a simple solution to this that I'm not getting because I'm working with dates. I want to be able to use the `difftime` function on this new visit variable to calculate the difference in time (in days) since visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata$visit <- pmin(mydata$visit_1,mydata$visit_2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
visit = visit_1
visit[is.na(visit)] = visit_2[is.na(visit)]
```